# Netlify cloud deploy - failure to get chromium.executablePath for browser launch

Tags: browser, typeerror, chromium, netlify, executable-path

I made a serverless functions at Netlify. It's a simple browser automation function with Puppeteer:

```
const chromium = require("@sparticuz/chromium");
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

chromium.setHeadlessMode = true; 
chromium.setGraphicsMode = false;

exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: chromium.args,
    defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
    executablePath: process.env.CHROME_EXECUTABLE_PATH || await 
    chromium.executablePath,
    headless: chromium.headless,
  });

await browser.close();

return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
        status: "The 'Element' function works!"        
    })
  };
}
```

The function fairly works at the local env. Yet, when deployed to the Netlify it returns the following error:

**This function has crashed**
An unhandled error in the function code triggered the following message:

**TypeError - The "*file*" argument must be of type string. Received function *executablePath***

```
Stack trace
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string. Received function executablePath
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:162:11)
    at normalizeSpawnArguments (node:child_process:528:3)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:726:13)
    at new Process (/var/task/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/launch.js:143:87)
    at launch (/var/task/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/launch.js:80:12)
    at ChromeLauncher.launch (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:90:54)
    at async Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/functions/element.js:11:21)
```

Seems to me a cloud server fails to get **chromium.executablePath** for the browser launch.

### Update

after I output the `const executablePath = await chromium.executablePath;`

I got the following:

```
async executablePath(input) {
    /**
     * If the `chromium` binary already exists in /tmp/chromium, return it.
     */
    if ((0, node_fs_1.existsSync)("/tmp/chromium") === true) {
        return Promise.resolve("/tmp/chromium");
    }
    /**
     * If input is a valid URL, download and extract the file. It will extract to /tmp/chromium-pack
     * and executablePath will be recursively called on that location, which will then extract
     * the brotli files to the correct locations
     */
    if (input && (0, helper_1.isValidUrl)(input)) {
        return this.executablePath(await(0, helper_1.downloadAndExtract)(input));
    }
    /**
     * If input is defined, use that as the location of the brotli files,
     * otherwise, the default location is ../bin.
     * A custom location is needed for workflows that using custom packaging.
     */
    input ?? (input = (0, node_path_1.join)(__dirname, "..", "bin"));
    /**
     * If the input directory doesn't exist, throw an error.
     */
    if (!(0, node_fs_1.existsSync)(input)) {
        throw new Error(`The input directory "${input}" does not exist.`);
    }
    // Extract the required files
    const promises = [lambdafs_1.default.inflate(`${input}/chromium.br`)];
    if (this.graphics) {
        // Only inflate graphics stack if needed            promises.push(lambdafs_1.default.inflate(`${input}/swiftshader.tar.br`));
    }
    if ((0, helper_1.isRunningInAwsLambda)()) {
        // If running in AWS Lambda, extract more required files
        promises.push(lambdafs_1.default.inflate(`${input}/aws.tar.br`));
    }
    // Await all extractions
    const result = await Promise.all(promises);
    // Returns the first result of the promise, which is the location of the `chromium` binary
    return result.shift();
}
```

Does it mean that  `await chromium.executablePath` is not resolved regardless of `await` ?

Comment: I am having the same error with     "puppeteer-core": "^19.8.0" and      "@sparticuz/chromium": "112.0" on AWS. Just leaving it as a data point

Answer (score 0):

My fault in typo. There should be:

```
await chromium.executablePath();
```

rather than:

```
await chromium.executablePath;
```